# No `trigger` to set column's default value from another column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to use no `trigger` to set column's default value from another column in the same table?

Simple demo looks like:

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_T (col1 INT, col2 INT);  

ALTER TABLE temp_T  
    ADD CONSTRAINT col1_def DEFAULT col2 * 2 FOR col1; 

INSERT INTO temp_T (col2) VALUES (7);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 128 Level 15 State 1 Line 2
>   The name "col2" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

I expected these values:

```
col1   col2
------------
 14      7
```

[Online TestDemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2fcc83e6c5453343b6be291ae960a2a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* create that column as a **computed column** instead of giving it a default:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_T (col1 INT, col2 AS col1 * 2 PERSISTED);
```

Now, if you insert the values:

```
INSERT INTO temp_T (col1) VALUES (7);
```

you do get 7 in `col1` and 14 in `col2`.

But this is now a computed column, meaning you **cannot** ever insert some other value into it - it's always going to be twice the value in `col1`. Not sure if that would work in your scenario - but as the error says: you cannot use another column in a default expression for a column.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use another column to calculate a default value for a table.

You can however create a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_T (col1 INT, col2 AS col1 * 2);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca13be5d4df4931bfe45ff1ee58768ff

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `DEFAULT VALUE` based on a different column. But then you may want to ask why you have such a requirement? If value of col2 is always going to be 2 * col1, then why do you want to store it in the DB and waste storage space?

If col2 is always 2 * col1, you can change your read query (or a stored procedure) to do that for you:

```
select col1, 2 * col1 as computed_col2 from temp_T
```

If you want a computed value, only when col2 is null, then you can do this:

```
select 
    col1, 
    case when col2 is null then col1 * 2 else col2 end as col2
from 
    temp_T
```

And if you you have some more complex logic you need to use a `trigger`.